# Are adult diapers feasible and permissible for use?

Tags: taharah

I am a field worker. When working I don't get a secluded place to answer the natures call (I get frequently due to some disability). If I go somewhere far even for a minute, the workers under me get irresponsible. A friend casually suggested an adult diaper.

Is it okay to use it? Does it break taharah? During lunch break, I may not find place or time to get rid of them so should I miss the prayer?

Answer (score 2):

When you will be wearing the diaper, then you remain in state of impurity, so you cannot pray at all. You have to find a way to keep some water with you to clean yourself somewhere, where no one can see you. Or just get some cardboard or any type of plastic, which you can keep there with you to cover yourself, like a wall around you, when you clean yourself, so no one can see you.